# Getting hours occupied in a day

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say I have a variable `DayHours` and a `DateTime` called `CurrentDay`.

I have events with a start date, an end date, and hours. They all fall within `CurrentDay`
If it is the last day of the event and the end date == `CurrentDay`, then I need the remainder. So if a day lasts 5 hours and an event is 14 hours and today is the last day, I would return 4.

If the event starts and ends on the same day, I return its hours. If an event is multiple days and `CurrentDay` is not the last day of the event, I return `DayHours`.

How could I do this in C#?

Comment: _"So if a day lasts 5 hours and an event is 14 hours and today is the last day, I would return 4."_ Huh? A sample would be great.

Comment: 5 + 5 + 4 = 3 days = 14 hours

Comment: "*I have an event with a start date, an end date and hours*" do you mean variables or some custom `EventArgs`? Show an example of some code?

Comment: You work 5 hour days?

Comment: No, if I work 5 hours the first day, 5 hours the second day, I'll then work 4 hours on the last day to get my 14 hours given that a work day is 5 hours.

Comment: @Shane.C He might be allocated to work 5 hours per day on a given project, and have 3 hours per day allocated to some other project.

Comment: @Shane.C Yes, doesn't everyone?

Comment: I suspect you have something like `public class FooEvent { DateTime StartDate; DateTime EndDate; double Hours; }`

Comment: @DaveRook He doesn't say 14 hours is 4 days, he says that it should return 4 hours on the last day (day 3).

Comment: @Servy - Thank you. Now this is clear! BUT, the answer should be 1 as he requires the remainder! (it's 14 hours, there is 1 hour left)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave the logic for it already:

```
if (StartDate.Date == EndDate.Date) { return Hours; }
else if (EndDate.Date != CurrentDay.Date) { return DayHours; }
else if (StartDate.Date <= CurrentDate.Date && EndDate.Date > CurrentDate.Date) { return Hours % DayHours; }
else return 0;
```

The variables may change, depending on what your actual code looks like, but this uses the data you say you are given.

Comment: Make sure you see the edited version.  My first one had the first line return DayHours, while it should return Hours.

Comment: Should probably add a `.Date` to each of the datetimes to ensure there is no time portion causing problems.  To be more robust it also may need to return 0 or throw an exception if the day doesn't land while the event is happening.

Comment: Thanks, @Servy.  That's a good idea.  I've put it into my answer.